# Set facebook permission for stream publish

Tags: android, facebook

I have a open session.when i try to publish friends wall post it says i don't have permission to do this.how can i set stream publish permission to already open session in android.

Comment: i'm confused with that code.its totally wrong i think. please can you tell me how to set permission for already open session

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an already open session, you should check whether it already has the "publish_stream" or "publish_action" permission, and if it doesn't, call requestNewPublishPermissions. Something like

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
if (!permissions.contains("publish_actions")) {
     Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"))
            .setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);
     session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the permission of publish as below :

> ```
> private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] { "publish_stream" };
> ```

And check this permission in the authorize method of facebook as below:

> ```
> public void loginAndPostToWall() throws CustomException
>   {
>     try
>     {
>         m_facebook.authorize(FacebookShareActivity.this, PERMISSIONS,
>                 Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
>     }
>     catch (Throwable p_e)
>     {
>         throw new CustomException(TAG + "Error in  loginAndPostToWall()", p_e);
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately, the Facebook object is now deprecated, so we should avoid using this.